# Series of Quaternions

Tags: c++, series, quaternions

Please excuse my ignorance on quaternions (trying to learn them as I type this). In the context of 3D graphics, suppose I have a point p1 which gets transformed by a series of quaternions from q0 to qn yielding to point p2. Knowing all the quaternions to get from p1 to p2, is it possible to do the reverse to get back to p1?

I tried something silly like this but it didn't give me what I was after:

```
int main(void)
{
    vmath::vec4 p1(4.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);
    print_vec4(p1);

    vmath::quaternion q1(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, M_PI);
    vmath::vec4 p2 = p1 * q1.asMatrix();
    print_vec4(p2);

    vmath::quaternion q2(q1);
    q2 = q2.conjugate();
    p2 = p2 * q2.asMatrix();
    print_vec4(p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am guessing now, but what would happen if you first normalize q1 before doing anything else? Or replace `q2 = q2.conjugate();` with `q2 = q2.conjugate() / (q2.length() * q2.length());`? EDIT: corrected mistake, it should be q2.length() squared.

Comment: you should post here http://math.stackexchange.com/ , maybe use a scripting language to familiarize yourself with quaternions and play a little with them before coding in C++ ( which is a way more tedious task the way you are doing it now ), remember that quaternion are composed of 4 elements so to speak : 1 scalar and 3 imaginary numbers; that's not even close to what you are doing. Pick a math book, before trying to use C++ for this .

Comment: Thank biapio! Normalizing seems to have done the trick. Will investigate more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T = q1 * q2 *...qn
  the inverse transform to this one is 
T^-1 = qn^-1 .. * q2^-1 * q1^1;
 where "^1" mean "inverse", for unit length quaternion we can reverse sign of "vector" (x,y,z) components for inverse operation.

And at least

p2 = T * p1;
and
p1 = T^-1 * p2